# Webpack CommonsChunkPlugin

Tags: webpack, chunks

I have a webpack configuration where when a package is used more than 3 times, it is move to `common` package.
I want to add an exception for one package which i don't want in `common` but is ued more than 3 times, how can i do that ?

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
   name: 'common',
   filename: `${configuration.webpack.filenameTemplate}.js`,
   minChunks: 3,
}),
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, using regexp you can do a pass on specific module by naming them like this :

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'specific package',
        filename: `${configuration.webpack.filenameTemplate}.js`,
        minChunks: ({ context }) => context && hasPathIn(/(\/|\\)node_modules(\/|\\)theNameOfYourPacakge(\/|\\), context),
      }),
```